# Exclude path from firewall security in symfony4

Tags: symfony, security, symfony4

I recently just started with Symfony 4 and having some problems with authentication in the security bundle, security.yaml file.

The security.yaml file has one firewall for the given API routes i want to control:

```
security:
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory: ~

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/portal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

I would like to restrict all routes from the root level except in this case the /portal route, which should be available for everyone. How am i able to do this.

Currently this gives me a `InsufficientAuthenticationException` Full `authentication is required to access this resource.` Exception. Is there something im missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define path of login form. With this path you are redirected to login. Without path, exception is thrown immediately.

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: in_memory
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
```

More info can be found in Symfony documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html